# jquery divide input value from total of other fields

Tags: jquery

I am certain this has come up on here before however I can't seem to connect the two required functions to produce the results I need.

I currently have the following code which adds the value of the first three fields together, this stage works correctly...

http://jsfiddle.net/mobius80/JwL4D/1/

HTML:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" id="the_input_id"><br>
    <input type="text" id="the_input_id1"><br>
    <input type="text" id="the_input_id2"><br>
    <select id="the_input_id3">
        <option value="0">Pay in full</option>
        <option value="52">Weekly</option>
        <option value="26">Fotnightly</option>
        <option value="13">Four weekly</option>
        <option value="12">Monthly</option>
    </select> <br>
    <input type="text" id="total"><br>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {

    $('#the_input_id').keyup(function() {  
    updateTotal();
    });

    $('#the_input_id1').keyup(function() {  
    updateTotal();
    });

    $('#the_input_id2').keyup(function() {  
    updateTotal();
    });
    $('#the_input_id3').keyup(function() {  
    updateTotal();
    });

    var updateTotal = function () {
      var input1 = parseInt($('#the_input_id').val());
      var input2 = parseInt($('#the_input_id1').val());
      var input3 = parseInt($('#the_input_id2').val());
      var input4 = parseInt($('#the_input_id3').val());

    if (isNaN(input1) || isNaN(input2) || isNaN(input3) || isNaN(input4)) {

      if(!input2){
          $('#total').val($('#the_input_id').val());
      }

      if(!input1){
            $('#total').val($('#the_input_id1').val());
      }

      if(!input3){
          $('#total').val($('#the_input_id2').val());
      }

      if(!input4){
          $('#total').val($('#the_input_id3').val());
      }


  } else {          
        $('#total').val(input1 + input2 + input3 / input4);
  }
};

var output_total = $('#total');

var total = input1 + input2  + input3  / input4;

   output_total.val(total);

});
```

The addition of the first three fields works perfectly however I am now trying to divide the total of that addition by the value selected in the select box and can't seem to get it to tie in with the total of the first series of additions.

Any help on this would be greatly appreicated.

As mentioned earlier, I have a semi-working jsfidle at http://jsfiddle.net/mobius80/JwL4D/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose your three inputs in parenthesis.
So change this:

```
input1 + input2  + input3  / input4;
```

to this:

```
(input1 + input2  + input3)  / input4;
```

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JwL4D/2/)

According to [Order of operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations), without paranthesis, `input3/input4` was calculated then added to `input1 + input2`

Comment: Thank you, worked a treat and showed me a fundamental error in the way I was trying to do this... wrapping first stage in () is obvious now but I clearly needed a point in the right direction... Cheers.